# Polynomial function to estimate the empirical density function

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, estimation, cumulative-distribution-function

Let's say I have a sample $X$ from any distribution (large enough to have a good approximation of the cumulative density function $F(x)$).
I want to have an "explicit function" that estimates the accumulated density function (maybe a polynomial function).

I tried to use a polynomial regression model to estimate F (x). Here is what i did:

```
set.seed(10)
x=c(rnorm(n = 99,1,1),4.6)
P = ecdf(x)
dataacum = data.frame(x=sort(x),acu=P(sort(x)))
model <- lm(dataacum$acu ~ dataacum$x +I((dataacum$x)^2)+I((dataacum$x)^3)+I((dataacum$x)^4)+I((dataacum$x)^5)+I((dataacum$x)^6))

E.A <- function(x){
  as.numeric(model$coefficients)[7]*x^6+  as.numeric(model$coefficients)[6]*x^5+
    as.numeric(model$coefficients)[5]*x^4  + as.numeric(model$coefficients)[4]*x^3 +
  as.numeric(model$coefficients)[3]*x^2+as.numeric(model$coefficients)[2]*x  + as.numeric(model$coefficients)[1]
    }
plot(dataacum$x,(dataacum$acu))
#lines(dataacum$x,E.A(dataacum$x),type = "l",col="red")
lines(seq(min(dataacum$x),max(dataacum$x),0.1),E.A(seq(min(dataacum$x),max(dataacum$x),0.1)),type = "l",col="blue")
lines(seq(min(dataacum$x),max(dataacum$x),0.1),pnorm(seq(min(dataacum$x),max(dataacum$x),0.1),1,1),type = "l",col="green")
```

I think it OK, but I have problems when X has outliers.

Any suggestions on how to improve my polynomial function or another better model, especially when I have a  outlier? or something much better than my idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think this will be interesting or useful? A good candidate for $F$ (a) fits  the data well and (b) is bounded, monotonic and generally behaves as any $F$ must by definition, including as $F \downarrow 0$ and $F \uparrow 1$. A 6th order polynomial might appear to satisfy (a) sometimes but none of (b) is automatically satisfied. Regardless, make you sure you plot the polynomial fits. Sooner or later with real data it will behave very badly. Unfortunately, this remains a dark and difficult art, with many named distributions most of which work well some of the time.

Comment: If you would like to find some candidate distributions, you can try running the sample data through my online statistical distribution fitter and see what it comes up with. It will fit over 80 named statistical distributions, and might turn up something useful. The URL is http://zunzun.com/StatisticalDistributions/1/

Comment: thanks Nick Cox, I want somehow to generate data from the "distribution of the sample", I need know or approximate F(x)

Comment: Hi, James Phillips. I'm not sure how to use your online statistical distribution fitter. Do you have an example?